# Always getting "not a symbolic link" message, while installing any package

Tags: centos, symlink, rpm, libraries

When I am installing any package in my centos 6.0 system, by yum or rpm, I always getting `/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib64/libreadXMLnew.so.1 is not a symbolic link` message.

There is never a problem in installation, but what is a need of softlink for this file, which I have manually copied? Is there any problem to the system with this?
The files I have copied was:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# ls -l /usr/lib64/libreadXMLnew*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 291414 Mar  5 16:31 /usr/lib64/libreadXMLnew.so.1
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 291414 Mar  5 15:28 /usr/lib64/libreadXMLnew.so.1.0
[root@localhost Downloads]#
```

Comment: Apparently RPM is supposed to create a `sym-link` instead it finds a regular file. It doesn't know what to do, hence it throws message.

Comment: Thanks,but why it is searching libreadXMLnew.so.1, I mean while installing any package, or updating any package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RPM(Red Hat Package Manager) verifies if all dependencies are installed and are as expected. `Symbolic Link` check is part of that verification.

I guess, you can skip link verification using `--nolinkto`.

or

Just remove regular file `libreadXMLnew.so.1` and :

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libreadXMLnew.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/libreadXMLnew.so.1
```

Symbolic links will be followed during linking/loading anyway.